# ASP.NET MVC notify of redirect with JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I've got a simple action method that lists some data from a repository.  The view for this action method uses simple paging.  The URL can be clicked on, or entered as `server:port/product/2` where 2 is the page number.  If the user enters in a page number that's greater than the number of pages of data, I want to redirect the user to `server:port/product/1` first and the notify them they were redirected.  The redirecting part works, but I can't seem to find a way to get the value passed to the action method.

EDIT: I used QueryString incorrectly in this question, what I really want is the parameter passed to the action method.

ProductController

```
 public ActionResult List(int page =1)
        {
            ProductsListViewModel model = new ProductsListViewModel();
            model.Products = _repository.Products.OrderBy(x => x.ProductId)
                                        .Skip((page -1) * 4)
                                        .Take(4);
            model.PagingInfo = new PagingInfo()
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = 4,
                TotalItems = _repository.Products.Count()
            };
            //this correctly redirects
            if (page > model.PagingInfo.TotalPages)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("List", new { page = 1 });
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

JavaScript

```
   var pageParam = "@Request.QueryString["id"]"
    var pageTotal = "@Model.PagingInfo.TotalPages";
    var    pageCurrent ="@Model.PagingInfo.CurrentPage";
    console.log('this is the current page: ' + pageCurrent);
    console.log(pageTotal);
    console.log(pageParam);

    function notifyRedirect(pageTotal, pageParam) {
        if (pageParam > pageTotal) {
            alert('you entered ' + pageParam + ', an invalid page parameter and were redirected');
            window.location = '/Product/List/1';
        }
    }
    notifyRedirect(pageTotal,pageParam);
```

Routes

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

When the page loads, the pageTotal and pageCurrent variables are printed to the console, but I get an empty string when trying to get the QueryString value.  Thinking that maybe I had the name of the parameter wrong, I decided to use the integral index of the QueryString and was presented with the error:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
```

How is it that `http://localhost:49997/product/list/2`, the fully qualified URL still gives me an empty QueryString value?  How can I use JS to notify the user of the redirect?

Comment: `QueryString` is part of a url that comes after "?" and consists of "&"-separated "name=value" pairs - you don't have it

Comment: @wootscootinboogie, Do you want to notify first and then redirect? or redirect first and then notify? Your javascript seems to be doing - Notify and redirect, but in your question, I see you alert and then redirect.

Comment: @ramiramilu I would like to redirect and then notify.  I don't know what I'm missing, but even using Request["id"] returns me nothing.  However, if I use Request.Url I can see the parameter as part of the URL, but I can't seem to get a hold of it for any JS use.

Comment: With MVC routing, Request does not carry `id` as a separate item (not in QueryString, not in Form, etc). `id` is part of url. It is MVC framework that extracts `id`'s value from url based on routing and passes it as action parameter if parameter name matches that in the route.

Comment: @Igor That's good to know.  Check the updated routes section, I removed all but one route and yet when I try to print the parameter my List view with @Request["id"] I get a blank string.  Why would this be happening?

Comment: Because there is no `Request["id"]` - I thought I made it clear in my previous comment. Make the method signature `List(int id =1)` or `List(int? id)` and you will have `id` passed to the method by the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but it seems like your question is "How do I get a query string value from a URL *without* a query string."

Both your redirect URL, `/Product/List/1` and your last URL mentioned, `http://localhost:49997/product/list/2`, have no query string, so any attempt to access anything in `Request.QueryString` is going to return null.

If you need something in the query string on the redirect then you need to add that to the redirect URL:

```
window.location = '/Product/List/1' + ((pageParam != '') ? '?id=' + pageParam : '');
```

Comment: I've conflated the parameter passed to the action method and a query string as the same thing.  What I'm really after is the parameter that was passed to the action method.

Comment: Well, that wouldn't be achieved with `Request.QueryString`. Try just `Request['page']` (since as @Igor noted your action accepts "page", not "id").

Answer (score 1):

Change the parameter name of the action method from `page` to `id` to agree with `MapRoute`. Then you don't need the first `MapRoute`, if you don't skip the name of the action in the url.

Comment: I had tried that as well.  As noted in the edit, what I really want to do is be able to get the parameter that was passed to the action method, and not a query string per se.